# Why is the jQuery extend method not copying my javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, object

I've looked into the many posts here regarding cloning and copying javascript objects, notably, these two topics:

- [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript)
- [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

It seems like it's not working for me, though.

Here is a snippet of code I'm using:

```
var copiedObject = {};

$.getJSON(URL, null, function (data) {
     copiedObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, data);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(copiedObject));
```

If I have my console log function within the JSON call, it outputs the proper values, but after the function, it's emptied out, and outputs `{}`.

I've tried using `copiedObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`, as well as the `clone(obj)` function from the "Copying an object in Javascript" post, all to no avail.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try `console.log(copiedObject);` (without the `JSON.stringify`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$.getJSON` fires an *Ajax request*, which by default runs *asyncronous*. Your `console.log` will fire before the request has finished. Fix it by moving the *console output* into the callback.

```
$.getJSON(URL, null, function (data) {
     copiedObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, data);
     console.log(JSON.stringify(copiedObject));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but will my object retain it's values outside of that function? I'm trying to limit the number of times I have to make this ajax request.

Comment: @Rail24: yes. If `copiedObject` is contained by a higher parent scope, you can access its value in any child-scope. All you need to make sure is, that every piece of code which accesses that variable executes *after* the request has finished.